# Angular Universal - parent component always refresh

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have noticed interesting behaviour while using angular universal. In short, the project was about a web portal, and I configured it in a way that categories are fetched from the backend via API call through the main component, but I have noticed that ngOnInit of the main component is called each time I change the rout even if the all the routes are child components to the main component. Is there any way I can make my main component call categories only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make the main component call the categories API only once, using a service to store the categories data.

You can create a service that makes an API call and stores the received ranges in a property.

Then, you can inject the service into both the main component and child components that need access to the category data.

I wrote a sample typescript code for you.Hope this will help to get an idea for your issue.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CategoriesService {
      categories: any;
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      fetchCategories() {
        if (!this.categories) {
          this.http.get('api/categories').subscribe(categories => {
            this.categories = categories;
          });
        }
      }
    }
    
    

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CategoriesService } from './categories.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-main',
    })
    export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.categoriesService.fetchCategories();
      }
    }
        


    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CategoriesService } from './categories.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-child',
    })
    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
      categories: any;
    
      constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.categories = this.categoriesService.categories;
      }
    }
```